# Should I exclude predictor variables if used to create a new one?

Tags: feature-selection

I have a dataset that includes race, gender, income, and family size. In addition, a variable for "sliding fee scale" tier is included, which is determined by income and family size. Should income and family size be excluded when fitting data to a logit model? Or should I first include all variables, examine correlations and then conduct a feature selection procedure to determine whether to include/exclude income and family size?

X1: Gender
X2: Family Size
X3: Income
X4: Tier (determined by X2 and X3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include all variables you will almost surely get high collinearity. In my view, the best diagnostic for this is the condition index; however, with non-continuous variables you may be better served by something like the 'perturb' package in `R`. Or, you can just assume the models would have a problem. (Especially since the levels of condition index that are problematic for logistic regression are, as far as I know, not well established).

You can compare models with different combinations of variables: a) Income only b) Family size only c) Income and family size and d) Tier.

I would base model comparison at least in part on substantive concerns; supplemented with AIC or BIC or some other IC. However, by excluding tier you can also look at interactions among income and family size.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Flom. You've helped me with a good number of options to try.